# regular expressions : Splitting by <!--nextpage--> in wordpress content

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I am in trouble because I do not know about regular expressions at php.

The original string is below.

```
$the_content = "
<h2>1page</h2><p>...</p>
<!--nextpage-->
<h2>2page</h2><p>...</p>
<!--nextpage-->
<h2>3page</h2><p>...</p>
<!--nextpage-->
<h2>4page</h2><p>...</p>
<!--nextpage-->
<h2>5page</h2><p>...</p>
";
```

The return array I want is below.

```
$matches = array(
  0 => '<h2>1page</h2><p>...</p><!--nextpage-->',
  1 => '<h2>2page</h2><p>...</p><!--nextpage-->',
  2 => '<h2>3page</h2><p>...</p><!--nextpage-->',
  3 => '<h2>4page</h2><p>...</p><!--nextpage-->',
  4 => '<h2>5page</h2><p>...</p>',
);

//or

$matches = array(
  0 => '<h2>1page</h2><p>...</p>',
  1 => '<!--nextpage-->',
  2 => '<h2>2page</h2><p>...</p>',
  3 => '<!--nextpage-->',
  4 => '<h2>3page</h2><p>...</p>',
  5 => '<!--nextpage-->',
  6 => '<h2>4page</h2><p>...</p>',
  7 => '<!--nextpage-->',
  8 => '<h2>5page</h2><p>...</p>',
);
```

php ver 7.1.0

Comment: What do you mean 'regular expressions at php'? What regular expressions do you know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a lookbehind to split after the HTML comment `(?<=<!--nextpage-->)`

Code sample:

```
<?php
$sourcestring='
<h2>1page</h2><p>...</p>
<!--nextpage-->
<h2>2page</h2><p>...</p>
<!--nextpage-->
<h2>3page</h2><p>...</p>
<!--nextpage-->
<h2>4page</h2><p>...</p>
<!--nextpage-->
<h2>5page</h2><p>...</p>
';
$matches=preg_split('/(?<=<!--nextpage-->)',$sourcestring);
echo print_r($matches,true);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Perfect!!